# Return Multiple Collections for use in an MVC4 asp.net View page

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I understand how to return a single collection (List<>) from a controller by returning View({mylist}); then referencing that with razor syntax @Model etc. inside the view page.  In my case, I have several different collections I want to use separately on the page.  I understand that I can make "the mother of all collections collection" and simply include the collections inside another collection (and return that one), but I'm wondering if there is some way in MVC4 that allows me to handle this situation more gracefully.

Thanks and Happy New Year!

Comment: use a viewmodel instead?  1st google hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx

Comment: thanks.  looks like a ViewModel is just a collection of collections (or other stuff). that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a view model. That is a regular class that will hold all the collection or properties you need in your view.

Check this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ViewBag` for every collection in controller and use those `ViewBag` variables View

In controller

```
public ActionResult HotelDetails(List<HotelDetailsModel> model)
        {           
            ViewBag.HotelDetails = model;
            return View();
        }
```

and in View

```
 @{
        List<HotelDetailsModel> hotels = (List<HotelDetailsModel>)ViewBag.SearchResultsModel;
        if (hotels.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (HotelDetailsModel item in hotels)
            {   
}
}
}
```